# Create new page or edit current one if year number is in URL

Tags: seo

I have a page on my site that contains information about a certain topic. That page was composed in 2013 and contains the number 2013 in its URL. I need to update it to reflect some changes that recently occurred (changes in this field are rare). Parts of the page will remain very similar/identical to the current version and others will be completely rewritten.

Can I create a new page with the number 2017 in the URL (with chunks of text that are identical to the 2015 page), or should I edit the current page and have it reflect all the latest information?

Comment: Just as a small comment, in case there was any confusion, Google basically doesn't care if a date is in the URL. It uses other methods to determine the freshness of content. As mentioned in the current answer, this is basically for people - - if you even choose to use a date at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky to answer, as there are two opposing factors in play. Your reaction depends upon how the current page is doing:

- Older articles that are well established tend to have better backlinks. If you see a lot of organic traffic, update it and note the date of the update below. Most top rated pages tend to be 3+ years old, as they've stood the test of time (evergreen content).
- Newer articles that improve upon old content can perform better - much better. It's upgrading. Taking high performing content and improving upon it is a very common content strategy. Changing the URL will force Google to consider it 'new'. It also means you can reach out to old backlinkers and ask them to update as well. The payoff takes time but the investment means you get better performing content.

The one reason I would be against a year in the URL is user based. Your CTR could be lower than an URL that looks more up to date. Users will see the year and be put off. Whenever you take into consideration ranking, put the user first. At the end of the day they're your target. Not Googlebots approval.

Comment: *Users will see the year and be put off.* So true! I do not recommend that a date exist within the URL path or file name at all. There may be cases where a date in the URL is preferred, however, I believe that those cases are rare. Cheers!!